# Model formula for glm regression with user-specified family

Tags: r, formula, regression, glm

**Background**

I am trying to predict the sales for a product line (y_test in the sample at the end).  Its sales for a timeperiod are based on all previous sales of another product (x_test) and how many of those previous sales are still being used.  It is not possible to directly measure the number of those previously-sold products that are still in use though, so a survival curve needs to be inferred.

For instance, if you make accessories for a particular smartphone model, the accessory sales are at least partly based on the number of those smartphones still being used.  (This is not homework, BTW.)

**Details**

I have some time series data and would like to fit a regression model using `glm` or something similar.  The relationship between the dependent and independent variable is this:
[image: regression formula]

Where p is the time period, y<sub>p</sub> is the dependent variable, x<sub>p</sub> is the independent variable, c<sub>0</sub> and c<sub>1</sub> are the regression coefficients, F<sub>t</sub> is a cumulative distribution function (such as `pgamma`), and e<sub>p</sub> are the residuals.

Through the first three time periods, the function would expand to something like this:

```
#y[1] = c0 + c1*(x[1]*(1-integrate(function(q) {pgamma(q, c2, c2/c3)}, 0, 1)$value))
#y[2] = c0 + c1*(x[1]*(1-integrate(function(q) {pgamma(q, c2, c2/c3)}, 1, 2)$value) + x[2]*(1-integrate(function(q) {pgamma(q, c2, c2/c3)}, 0, 1)$value))
#y[3] = c0 + c1*(x[1]*(1-integrate(function(q) {pgamma(q, c2, c2/c3)}, 2, 3)$value) + x[2]*(1-integrate(function(q) {pgamma(q, c2, c2/c3)}, 1, 2)$value) + x[3]*(1-integrate(function(q) {pgamma(q, c2, c2/c3)}, 0, 1)$value))
```

**So, I have historical data for x<sub>p</sub> and y<sub>p</sub>, and I want to get the values for the coefficients/parameters c<sub>0</sub>, c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, and c<sub>3</sub> that minimize the residuals.**

**I think the solution is to use `glm` and create a custom family, but I'm not sure how to do that.**  I looked at the code for the `Gamma` family but didn't get very far.  I have been able to do the optimization "manually" using `nlminb`, but I would much prefer the simplicity and usefulness (i.e. `predict` and others) offered by `glm` or similar functions.

Here is some example data:

```
# Survival function (the integral part):
fsurv<-function(q, par) {
  l<-length(q)
  out<-vapply(1:l, function(i) {1-integrate(function(x) {pgamma(x, par[1], par[1]/par[2])}, q[i]-1, q[i])$value}, FUN.VALUE=0)
  return(out)}

# Sum up the products:
frevsumprod <- function(x,y) {
  l <- length(y)
  out <- vapply(1:l, function(i) sum(x[1:i]*rev(y[1:i])), FUN.VALUE=0)
  return(out)}

# Sample data:
p<-1:24 # Number of periods
x_test<-c(1188, 2742, 4132) # Sample data
y_test<-c(82520, 308910, 749395, 801905, 852310, 713935, 624170, 603960, 640660, 553600, 497775, 444140) # Sample data
c<-c(-50.161147,128.787437,0.817085,13.845487) # Coefficients and parameters, from another method that fit the data

# Pad the data to the correct length:
pad<-function(p,v,padval=0) {
  l<-length(p)
  padv<-l-length(v)
  if(padv>0) (v<-c(v,rep(padval,padv)))
  return(v)
}
x_test<-pad(p,x_test)
y_test<-pad(p,y_test,NA)

y_fitted<-c[0+1]+c[1+1]*frevsumprod(x_test,fsurv(p,c[(2:3)+1])) # Fitted values from regression

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(p,y_test,y_fitted))+geom_point(aes(p,y_test))+geom_line(aes(p,y_fitted)) # Plot actual and fit
```

Comment: Thanks @DWin.  I edited the question, but still haven't gotten any attempts to answer it.  Do you have other suggestions for posing the question better?  And BTW, I think almost all of the problem statement is relevant to any potential answer, and not just a recounting of my "failed efforts".

Comment: I suggest you flag this with a request for migration to CrossValidated. (... or you could just cross-post it there with a note that  it has not gotten a response on SO.)

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with `glm`. The `family` in `glm` specifies how the linear predictor is connected with the mean value of y. See `?family` and [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model). In particular, you would need to be able to write a `family` list with (some of) the functions like:

```
> fam <- poisson()
> str(fam)
List of 12
 $ family    : chr "poisson"
 $ link      : chr "log"
 $ linkfun   :function (mu)  
 $ linkinv   :function (eta)  
 $ variance  :function (mu)  
 $ dev.resids:function (y, mu, wt)  
 $ aic       :function (y, n, mu, wt, dev)  
 $ mu.eta    :function (eta)  
 $ initialize:  expression({  if (any(y < 0))  stop("negative values not allowed for the 'Poisson' family")  n <- rep.int(1, nobs| __truncated__
 $ validmu   :function (mu)  
 $ valideta  :function (eta)  
 $ simulate  :function (object, nsim)  
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "family"
> 
> fam <- Gamma()
> str(fam)
List of 12
 $ family    : chr "Gamma"
 $ link      : chr "inverse"
 $ linkfun   :function (mu)  
 $ linkinv   :function (eta)  
 $ variance  :function (mu)  
 $ dev.resids:function (y, mu, wt)  
 $ aic       :function (y, n, mu, wt, dev)  
 $ mu.eta    :function (eta)  
 $ initialize:  expression({  if (any(y <= 0))  stop("non-positive values not allowed for the 'gamma' family")  n <- rep.int(1, n| __truncated__
 $ validmu   :function (mu)  
 $ valideta  :function (eta)  
 $ simulate  :function (object, nsim)  
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "family"
```

where `eta` refers to the linear predictor. I.e. at-least you will need to specify an inverse link function, `linkinv`, which **only** depends on the co-variates through a dot product between the parameters and the co-variates. Yours does not as it depends on c_2 and c_3 in a non-linear way.